# Careers: multiple locations

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I split my time between two cities that are 70 miles apart (this is a long distance in the UK). I would like to list both as my location in my CV on careers.stackoverflow.com, but I get only one choice. Please allow multiple location values.

I know that I can enter multiple locations in the "where do you want to work" section, but this is lower down the CV and doesn't quite match my situation (where I am really in both cities).

Comment: 112km is a long distance *anywhere*.

Comment: Commuting 100 or more miles is not uncommon in the US. It is very uncommon in Europe.

Comment: Commuting 112km in Iceland is crossing half the country. :P (i kid)

Comment: In Holland you cross the entire country (east to west, not north to south) :P

Comment: Actually a 60-70 mile commute each way isn't that uncommon in the UK. I'm commuting 60 miles and I know a few people who do a lot more each day.

Answer (score 4):

It is unlikely that employers will be searching on your personal location; this is mostly included for informational purposes.

The locations they will be searching on are at the bottom of your CV under **Where do you want to work?**, and can include multiple locations, as many as you want.

Comment: While I can see where you're coming from, what about those of us who spend time in multiple countries (US an UK in my case, I can legally work both in the US and the EU)?