# How do I specify upstate New York as a desired region?

Tags: feature-request, jobs, location

When I tried typing in "upstate new york", it was replaced with "New York, New York United States", clearly *not* the region I intended. For now I'm just listing "Syracuse, New York", but I'd really like to specify a broader region than that, without having to list every major city in the area.

Comment: I had an issue with entering New York, United States it kept replacing it with NYC.  If you enter "`New York State United States`" it figures it out and puts "`New York United States`" but I don't think you can put "Upstate" -- you'll have to put each major city in Update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now you are limited to whole states, whole cities, counties, or zip codes.  Would be nice to have phone number area code, and "region" option, or even a "within 100 miles of zip code/city" option.

The reality, though, is that in the database your locations are stored as lat/lon pairs, and it's the employer search that's important.

Ideally you should be able to enter "lat, lon, distance" which would give a very good flexible granularity, and would enable employers to search just as easily as they do now.  You'd have to do more work on your end to convert "Upstate NY" to "lat/lon/distance" but you'd be in control of it.

Here are the details of how they actually use/convert the region into a lat/lon pair and bounding box:

[Careers Locations - how am I supposed to use this? Radius of interest?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/careers-locations-how-am-i-supposed-to-use-this-radius-of-interest)

There's no way, currently, for you to enter your own lat/lon/bounding box trio, but since it uses yahoo's query you might be able to play around with yahoo and find the correct regional entry to generate a single, or set, of bounding boxes that you like.  I suspect that you can select a combination of counties and zip codes to meet your needs.

But you may consider simply including your local area, and then all of new york state.  When in doubt, be inclusive and you can selectively reject offers for interviews outside your area.

Comment: great answer! one small clarification: Yahoo does support counties, so you should be able to enter a county name in the box and have it generate the correct bounding rectangle.

Comment: My main concern with being inclusive is that NYC is over half the population of upstate NY, and probably more than half the programmers. I guess I will use the list of counties approach.

Comment: Jeff: I'll file this separately too, but while Yahoo supports counties, the Careers UI does not tell you whether it used just a county or switched to the whole state.

Answer (score 1):

You may enter counties as well, so how about using Onondaga County?

Yahoo maps will give you somewhat of an idea of the area:

http://maps.yahoo.com/#mvt=m&lat=43.021431&lon=-76.197708&zoom=10&q1=Onondaga%20County