# Careers geographical search

Tags: feature-request, jobs, search

As any job site, the careers section has a search on city, state/country and a number of miles...  However, a regional approach like "West Coast", "East Coast", "Europe", "Latin-America", ... (or even "Remote") would be extremely easy to implement and make the Stack Exchange careers web site something unique.

By when can we have this fantastic feature?

Comment: Related, maybe dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29458/how-do-i-specify-upstate-new-york-as-a-desired-region

Comment: @ShadowWizard: thanks for the link, and I understood already that that's the limit, but IMHO, a simple DB set would take care of that limitation and make Stack Exchange Careers (=SEC?) something unique that  would attract tons of new users...

Comment: Pretty much anything that you can enter into Google works with the job search... entering [Europe](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=Europe&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles) as a search term will constrain the geo-search area to all of Europe within 20 miles of that bounding box. Same for [West Coast, USA](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=West+Coast%2C+USA&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles).

Comment: Hmmm scrap that. West Coast, USA clearly does not do what it says on the tin. Europe works though.

Comment: @Dean yup, this doesn't work, maybe devs get different results or something like that?

Comment: @ShadowWizard this will also be susceptible to the advertising region filtering described in [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251829/all-jobs-showing-only-12-jobs-for-users-from-japan/251912#comment822786_251912). So if you're not in Europe you may not see many Europe jobs. Using my regular user account I see 997 jobs in Europe at the moment (I'm in Dublin).

Comment: Searching for remote jobs is already possible: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/remote

Comment: @DeanWard: Actually strings in your link to http://imgur.com/h0C2Zoo seem to work...  Would you care to convert that comment to an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pretty much anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pd52b.jpg) that you can enter into Google works with the job search.

Entering continents such as [Europe](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=Europe&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles) as a search term will constrain the geo-search area to all of Europe within 20 miles of that bounding box.

As Max mentioned we also support searching for [remote](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/remote) positions. This is exposed in the UI as the 'Allows Remote' option:

[image: Allows Remote]

Comment: Accepted, upvoted, edited to include the comments and finally: "Thank you!" **;-)**