# Careers: Location does not work well for large metro areas

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, location

I live and work in Southern California.  Southern California is a large geographical area and I have not been able to come up with a good way to describe the region I am prepared to work.

The `Los Angeles, California United States` location is far too open-ended .. covering nearly a thousand square miles.  On the other hand, the next level down (specific towns/zip codes) is far too granular.

My recommendation is to allow the location field to accept free text, so that we can enter the local "slang" designations that convey great meaning locally.  Perhaps there can be a way to associate the text with a known metro area for searching.  For instance, the terms `South Bay` and `Valley` have specific meanings when associated with metro Los Angeles.  They are both in the City of Los Angeles, but are 60 miles and 90 minutes apart!

Note: I believe that folks in Chicago, Seattle-Tacoma, South Florida, and many other places have the same kind of problem.

---

[Adam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29496/careers-location-does-not-work-well-for-large-metro-areas/29499#29499) doesn't think this will work because the employer search requires specificity.  However, specific searches are counter-productive in an area such as metro LA.  Consider the [Torrance, CA](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=torrance,+CA&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=37.735377,71.71875&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Torrance,+Los+Angeles,+California&ll=33.835849,-118.340629&spn=0.309701,0.560303&z=11) area.  A search for `Torrance, California United States` is far too small, but a search for `Los Angeles, California United States` is far too large.In fact, the employer wants to search for "Metro LA - South Bay" to get Torrance, Carson, Redondo Beach, San Pedro, Palos Verdes, and so on.  The alternative is to require the employer to repeat searches for each "sub-city", or to require candidates to put in a whole lot of locations.  Neither is optimal.

Craigslist is a good example of splitting big areas into regions to make searches more effective.  [Craigslist LA](http://losangeles.craigslist.org/) has 6 "regions", and you can search for all of LA or for a region.  OTOH [Craigslist Orange County](http://orangecounty.craigslist.org/) has no regions.  But in both, the poster can indicate their specific location within the region.

If we allow the creation of "regions" in big metro areas, the locals (to whom they have meaning) will quickly get them sensible.  Perhaps the moderators can enlist locals from the metro areas to help define the areas.  I volunteer for Southern California!

---

Interesting.  A [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29772/when-i-enter-a-county-on-careers-the-location-field-shows-the-whole-state) was asked about county names and colloquial regions not showing up properly, and Mr. Dalgas indicated that he improved the parsing of YQL responses.  I checked, and now the regions I mentioned seem to work.  So, I will accept his answer to this question.  How the regions show up in searches remains to be seen!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will continue to improve our location based search as we see how employers are actually using it.  Currently the employers have the ability to search within a radius of a location and we may offer more flexibility on defining regions of where you're willing to take a position.  At this point we are erring on the side of including more results to the employers and allowing them to contact you to ultimately decide if you want to commute to that location.

Comment: Are you saying that if the employer in my example puts in a 25 mile radius that employer will see candidates in Carson, San Pedro, Redondo Beach, etc?

Comment: If those places are within 25 miles and there are searchable CVs within those limits then - yes.

Answer (score 2):

One of the features of careers.so is that employers can search very specifically by location.  Having a free-form location field would render that function useless.

I agree that we should be able to choose our own location and bounding box, though.  See

[How do I specify upstate New York as a desired region?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29458/how-do-i-specify-upstate-new-york-as-a-desired-region/29478#29478)

and

[Careers Locations - how am I supposed to use this? Radius of interest?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/careers-locations-how-am-i-supposed-to-use-this-radius-of-interest)

for similar questions and feature requests.

Comment: I understand, but this kind of specificity **does not work** in areas like Metro LA.  There needs to be a middle ground.