# UK careers locations are formatted unconventially/inconsistently

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

If I enter my county (Kent) as a location on the careers site, it comes back as

```
Kent County, England United Kingdom
```

which looks very odd to a British person.

The main thing wrong is that no county in the UK has the word "County" at the end of its name, it should just be "Kent".

In the case of counties such as Lancashire or Nottinghamshire the word "county" is even more redundant as that is what "[shire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shire)" means.

```
Nottinghamshire County, England United Kingdom
```

This bug seems to be a result of using American conventions for all locations.

Things get even more confused when you consider that there are some counties that have "County" at the start of their name (mostly in Northern Ireland).  If I enter my location as County Durham, I get this redundant creation:

```
County Durham County, England United Kingdom
```

But the rules aren't consistent.  If I enter County Down, I get this, which is not redundant, just [backwards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/County_Down):

```
Down County, Northern Ireland United Kingdom
```

A more minor gripe is that there should be a comma between England/Northern Ireland/Wales/Scotland and United Kingdom (although it's not typical usage to specify both).

**Related:** [Careers wont let me list Reykjavik, Iceland as location](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24962/careers-wont-let-me-list-reykjavik-iceland-as-location), [Careers: Location does not work well for large metro areas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29496/careers-location-does-not-work-well-for-large-metro-areas)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We do append county to the result - for US based counties it looked very strange and could lead to confusion IE. Kent - Kent, WA is a city but Kent is also a county - I'll add logic to the location that if the result is a type of county and it is located in the US, append county.

Comment: That was quick, thanks.  I would still suggest some kind of punctuation/separator between the "state" and country.  It looks odd without it, particularly if you live in "Perth, Western Australia Australia"